# My Resource class is not finding the service bean defined in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot

I have defined a Student Service Component:

```
@Component
public class StudentService {

    private final StudentDao studentDao;

    @Autowired
    public StudentService(@Qualifier("fakeDao") StudentDao studentDao) {
        this.studentDao = studentDao;
    }

    //for the sake of relevance not putting other methods here, but I have all CRUD methods defined here 
    //in the class.
}
```

My StudentResource Class is as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/students")
public class StudentResource {

    @Autowired
    private final StudentService studentService;

    public StudentResource(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }
}
```

When I run the application I get the following error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    [2m2020-10-05 22:06:19.236[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m7228[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 
    
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
    
Description:
    
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.centene.demo.resource.StudentResource required a bean of type 'org.centene.demo.service.StudentService' that could not be found.
    
    
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.centene.demo.service.StudentService' in your configuration.
```

just some info on the versions being used:
JAva 1.8
Spring boot 2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `StudentDao` class that you are trying to Autowire. I think you forgot to make bean configurations for `StudentDao`. Put `@Configuration` or `@Service` at the top of your `StudentDao` class declaration and try again. It should work.

Comment: I tried this and still the error does not go away.  Let me put the code in the StudentDao Interface.

Comment: public interface StudentDao {
 int insertNewStudent(UUID studentId, Student student);  .....}

Comment: it is interface, where is the interface implementation? You put annotation into a implementation class

Comment: @Repository("fakeDao")
public class FakeStudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {
 
 private final Map<UUID, Student> database;
 

 public FakeStudentDaoImpl() {

  database = new HashMap<>();
 }

Comment: Ok I have removed the annotation from the interface StudentDao and pasted the code in the class implementation.  FakeStudentDaoImpl which is annotated with @Repository

Comment: One more thing I am trying to learn Spring Boot here, and its not that I know the workings of it.. So would like to learn how to fix such issues.  Any guidance would be very helpful...

Comment: Currently no annotation on the StudentDao interface and the class which implements it has @Repository.  Still getting the same error.

Comment: Is StudentDAO repository?

Comment: if you are new, I highly recommend you https://spring.io/guides#getting-started-guides

Comment: for example, https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ is about how to use repositories

Comment: I am learning this course through Udemy and ran into this issue not sure what wrong I am committing here, as I followed the same steps stated in the course

Comment: the answer to your question is FakeStudentDaoImpl which is the implementation of StudentDao is a repository. Still getting the same error..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.
Apparently the issue was with my package structure.
The package of the class StudentService was written wrongly starting with "org.centene.demo..." rather than "com.centene.demo..".  This is important as the other packages all started with com.centene.demo